# What is the longest hero fight in the Marvel universe?

Tags: marvel

Many heroes are known for being able to fight for an extended period of time.
What is the longest fight fought without a break with a superhero involved?

Ruling out 2 cosmic entities fighting in a dimension where time doesn't exist.
Or for an infinite amount of time loop hole. Where fight involved playing with time or outside of time.

Comment: Are you asking within the Marvel cinematic universe or among comic universes etc. as well?

Comment: @Kozaky It's tagged [[tag:marvel]] and [[tag:comics]] and mentions _"Marvel universe"_ not MCU so it appears to be Marvel as a whole meaning MCU and comics are fine.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot If it's tagged marvel and comics, why would the MCU (which is distinctly **not** comics) be fine?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist From the wording it sounds like they're asking in general rather than specifically comics but good point. I suppose I wrote the previous comment to prove to the first commenter that this is more about the general terms and certainly about the comics rather than the MCU as they were thinking.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I should have worded it better; I was asking what universe in particular the OP was asking about (if they were asking about any in particular at all, or just any of them), using the MCU as an example.

Comment: @Kozaky, The question is about the Marvel univers in general, while answer using MCU are welcom.
I forgot to include the tag because when speaking about long fight, Because I didn't think MCU had answer to offer without using time loop.
Would you like the MCU tag to be added or the comics to be removed?

Comment: What is a fight without break for 2 speedster? Does fight that happends only in one mind count(hypnosis, dream, etc)? For a dream fight how do we measure time, as time in a dream could easly be day when it's only sec pass in universe?

Answer (score 6):

Any possible contender for this title that pops into my mind involves Thor or the Hulk.  There has to be that major power level to go the long haul.

So, the following image involves Thor **and** the Hulk!  From "Defenders" #10 (1973).  The caption describes the two have been locked, muscle to muscle, for an hour.
[image]

Then a second contender came to mind.  From "Avengers" #22 (1999).  According to Iron Man, they've been fighting Ultron duplicates for *hours*.  Apparently "mere mortals" can go the distance!
(*sidenote: a few pages away from the legendary "Ultron, we would have words with thee!" scene*)
[image]

Comment: Thor was my first thought, I can easly picture him on a piramyd of corpses. Slaughtering the whole planet. Fighting no end waves of minions for weeks.